# 404 not found - but most certainly on server

Tags: html, http-status-code-404, directory, file-not-found

`Hello,`

I am getting this 404 not found error, while the file is most certainly on the server. All other files can be found, but I tried adding an icon folder and since then every file I upload to my server cannot be found by my browser.
How is this possible and can this be fixed?

Kind regards,

Isaiah van Hunen

P.S. You are of course free to visit my website and possibly find out what's going on. Maybe some bad setting? I didn't change any though.

---

1. Via directadmin (FTP shows the same),

[image: Via directadmin]

2. Directly on my website

[image: Directly on my website]

Comment: What web server are you using, and on what operating system? My first guess would be that the folder and/or files have the wrong permissions to be read by the server.  If it's *nix, could you show the output of `ls -alR` for the public_html folder please?

Comment: @MarkSmith PHP tells me Linux vserver58.axc.nl with Apache, does this answer your question (don't know too much about servers). I share your first guess, but the icons folder has permissions 755, just like all my folders, with my FTP account as owner; the file itself 644 with the FTP owner too. As do all my other files, and they are accessible...

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to give the folder the right permissions so it can be used via the web ? Also what type of server are you running this on ?

https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. PHP tells me Linux vserver58.axc.nl with Apache, does this answer your question (don't know too much about servers). The icons folder has permissions 755, just like all my folders, with my FTP account as owner; the file itself 644 with the FTP owner too. As do all my other files, and they are accessible...

Comment: Now the icons folder is in the main dir that the rest of them are in right ? like where the index.html and the image/ folder is at?

Comment: Now are the photos in /icon all under the right permissions? Just cuz the folder has the right permissions the photos might not. Let me know I know I can help you with this if i had more information.

Comment: The icons is in my main dir indeed, as visible in the DirectAdmin screenshot (with my index.html and such). The photos in the /icons folder all have 644 permissions...

Comment: If that don't work try setting the folder to 777 for a min or 775 and then test to see if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, putting it in an ".nl/icons/.." folder resulted in `Not Found` but in another folder such as ".nl/ico/..." - no problems at all!

Thanks to anyone who contributed to this post. I still don't understand the matter with naming a folder "icons", but oh well...